# Reclassify a vector based in another vector R

Tags: r, sorting, dataframe, vector

I have two vectors, or two columns of a data.frame and I want to the first column represent values let's say A and the second groups G, I want to change the groups based on the maximum values of A  by G, then I want to change the values of G so that the group are ordered by max A. For example

```
df <-"A  G
1.0 1
2.0 1
2.6 2
1.0 2
2.0 2
1.0 3
2.3 3"

df <- read.table(textConnection(df), header=TRUE)

aggregate(df$A, by=list(df$G), max)
```

then max by group are 2 2.6 2.3, and group 3 have to become 2, group 2 -> 3, and group 1 stays the same.

result should be

```
 A  G
1.0 1
2.0 1
2.6 3
1.0 3
2.0 3
1.0 2
2.3 2
```

It's easy to use agreggate or dplyr to obtain the max

```
require(dplyr)

df %>% group_by(G) %>% summarise(Amax=max(A))
```

but I don't figure out how to change the groups.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `dense_rank()` on the max value by group.  Although it's not clear what the result should be if max values are tied.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(G = dense_rank(ave(A, G, FUN = max)))

    A G
1 1.0 1
2 2.0 1
3 2.6 3
4 1.0 3
5 2.0 3
6 1.0 2
7 2.3 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `data.table` and `match`:

```
df=as.data.table(df)
df[,maxg:=max(A),by=G][,G:=match(maxg,sort(unique(maxg)))][,maxg=NULL]
```

Answer (score 0):

We could join `df` with a grouped - ordered - renamed version of itself, and get the new group:

```
library(data.table)

setDT(df)

df[df[, max(A), by = G][order(-V1)][, newG := .I], on = "G"]

     A G  V1 newG
1: 2.6 2 2.6    1
2: 1.0 2 2.6    1
3: 2.0 2 2.6    1
4: 1.0 3 2.3    2
5: 2.3 3 2.3    2
6: 1.0 1 2.0    3
7: 2.0 1 2.0    3
```

What is in there:

`df[, max(A), by = G]` gives you a data.table of the max values of A in each group G.

`[order(-V1)]` sorts the values of `max(A)` (stored as V1) in descending order.

`[, newG := .I]` assings to variable `newG` the row number.

`X[Y, on = "Z"]` is the syntax for table joins in data.table (Join tables X and Y on variable Z)

If you want to remove `V1`, then it's achieved by appending to the end of the chained command: `[, V1 := NULL]`.